# Windows7 won't boot after upgrading Ubuntu to 16.04

Tags: windows-7, boot, multi-boot, ubuntu-16.04

I've recently upgraded ubuntu to 16.04 and my working dual-boot installation doesn't work anymore. Ubuntu loads fine, but Win7(loader) stops at blinking cursor on black screen. I've tried a few solutions, e.g. Boot-repair. There were obviously some issues during repair, which I don't understand.

I have two separate 500GB disks and Windows installation is present and OK, because ubuntu is recognizing it as connected medium.

This is what boot-repair advised me to post: http://paste2.org/GvYJpMWe

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your output it looks like your grub file is pointing to a 488mb partition on your second drive "sdb" to boot your windows. However your windows installation is present on your first drive "sda".

Here is what i would try first. Run "sudo update-grub" then restart. If you cannot boot to your windows install then go back into linux and run "sudo grub-install /dev/sdb". If you are still having trouble loading windows i recommend modifying your grub.cfg file. Try those first and let me know if it works.

I would aslo give this utility a try. Its what i use when im having trouble booting anything. Rescatux: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/